# How to border data using a Google Apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a list that repeats in the same order and I have to format it manually by pressing Alt+H+B+A

Can I do it through a script?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to choose your data range.
Then set border to selected data range.

Here's document from developers.google.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
// Sets borders on the top and bottom, but leaves the left and right unchanged
// Also sets the color to "red", and the border to "DASHED".
cell.setBorder(true, null, true, null, false, false, "red", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DASHED);
```

Here's the link for your reference.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBorder(Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,String,BorderStyle)

Here's the function can make what you need.

```
function set_databorder() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for(i=1;i<=120;i=i+13){
      for(j=1;j<=30;j=j+3){
        ss.getRange(i,j,13,3).setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, "green", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOUBLE);
      }
  }

}
```